# How to avoid global variable for modules when transpiling from es6 to es5 with browserify

Tags: ecmascript-6, browserify, commonjs, babeljs, es6-modules

I am transpilling es6 to es5 with browserify and babel like this:

```
concat: {
            options: {
                sourceMap: false
            },
            dist: {
                src: ["Scripts/app/another.js", "Scripts/app/employee.js"],
                dest: "Scripts/app/built.js"
            }
        },
browserify: {
            dist: {
                options: {
                    transform: [
                    ["babelify", { "presets": ["es2015"] }]]
                },
                files: {
                    "Scripts/app/expParser.js": "Scripts/app/built.js"
                }
            }
        }
```

In my employeeModule.js:

```
 export const n=10;
```

In my employee.js:

```
import {d} from "./employeeModule.js";
 console.log(d) //10
```

And now the issue is when I am calling console.log(d) in another file even though I am not doing an "*import*", another.js:

```
console.log(d) //10
```

I mention that I am concatenating: employee.js and another.js together to make a single call when load for this file in the browser. Both of this files are IIFEs.
How can I prevent accessing the "d" value in another.js file?

The compiled code is something like this:
 `var _employeeModule = require("./employeeModule");` 
  and is global to all the functions.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm sure you don't need the `concat` task.
Browserify does all necessary [concatenation](https://github.com/substack/browserify-handbook#how-browserify-works) and [module isolation](https://github.com/substack/browserify-handbook#exports) for you. All you need is writing imports.

For example, you can remove the `concat` task, and then leave only these two lines in your `built.js`:

```
import './another.js';
import './employee.js';
```

After a build you'll find your `expParser.js` executing both of these modules with variables not visible from the outside for each of them. Without any wrapping the modules into IIFEs manually.
I guess this is close to your needs.

**P.S.** Please, don't forget to mention that you are using `grunt` next time.

Comment: Thank you! Sorry for not mentioning that I am using grunt!